# Semi-supervised logistic regression classification model not functioning properly?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I want to use semisupervised learning in logistic regression to predict potential fake reviews using user metadata (such as friend count and review length) collected into csv files

I have two csv files and they all contain the columns "Review Text" "Rating" "Date" "User Review Count" "Feedback Useful" Feedback Funny" "Feedback Cool" "Friend Count" "Text Length" and "Review Class" (These are the columns I want to use in order to determine if the reviews are real or fake)

The "Review Class" column tells if the review is fake or not. It's labeled with either "Real" or "Fake" or "Unmarked"

The first csv file titled "Yelp Training Set" contains reviews that are either marked as "Real" or "Fake" in the "Review Class" column. This is to be used to train the model

[image: Yelp Training Set]

The csv file titled "Yelp Testing Set" is the set that I want to use to test the model. These reviews have been collected from business pages and they have been labeled as "Unmarked" in the "Review Class"

[image: Yelp Testing Set]

I was able to get the codes that I attempted to "work" but I'm getting no results.

This is what the first code looks like:

```
import pandas as pd
import nltk
import string
import re
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.stem.porter import PorterStemmer
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, classification_report, confusion_matrix
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer

# Load the data
df_train = pd.read_csv("Yelp Training Set.csv")
df_test = pd.read_csv("Yelp Testing Set.csv")

# Preprocessing functions
def text_lowercase(text):
    return text.lower()

def remove_numbers(text):
    result = re.sub(r'\d+', '', text)
    return result

def remove_punctuation(text):
    translator = str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)
    return text.translate(translator)

def remove_whitespace(text):
    return " ".join(text.split())

def remove_stopwords(text):
    stop_words = set(stopwords.words("english"))
    word_tokens = word_tokenize(text)
    filtered_text = [word for word in word_tokens if word not in stop_words]
    return " ".join(filtered_text)

stemmer = PorterStemmer()

def stem_words(text):
    word_tokens = word_tokenize(text)
    stems = [stemmer.stem(word) for word in word_tokens]
    return " ".join(stems)

lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()

def lemmatize_word(text):
    word_tokens = word_tokenize(text)
    lemmas = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(word, pos='v') for word in word_tokens]
    return " ".join(lemmas)

# Preprocess the "Review Text" column
df_train["Review Text"] = df_train["Review Text"].apply(text_lowercase)
df_train["Review Text"] = df_train["Review Text"].apply(remove_numbers)
df_train["Review Text"] = df_train["Review Text"].apply(remove_punctuation)
df_train["Review Text"] = df_train["Review Text"].apply(remove_whitespace)
df_train["Review Text"] = df_train["Review Text"].apply(remove_stopwords)
df_train["Review Text"] = df_train["Review Text"].apply(stem_words)
df_train["Review Text"] = df_train["Review Text"].apply(lemmatize_word)

df_test["Review Text"] = df_test["Review Text"].apply(text_lowercase)
df_test["Review Text"] = df_test["Review Text"].apply(remove_numbers)
df_test["Review Text"] = df_test["Review Text"].apply(remove_punctuation)
df_test["Review Text"] = df_test["Review Text"].apply(remove_whitespace)
df_test["Review Text"] = df_test["Review Text"].apply(remove_stopwords)
df_test["Review Text"] = df_test["Review Text"].apply(stem_words)
df_test["Review Text"] = df_test["Review Text"].apply(lemmatize_word)

# Preprocess the "Rating" and "Review Class" columns
rating_map = {"1 star": 1, "2 stars": 2, "3 stars": 3, "4 stars": 4, "5 stars": 5}
df_train["Rating"] = df_train["Rating"].map(rating_map)
df_test["Rating"] = df_test["Rating"].map(rating_map)

df_train["Review Class"] = df_train["Review Class"].map({"Real": 0, "Fake": 1, "Unmarked": -1})
df_test["Review Class"] = df_test["Review Class"].map({"Real": 0, "Fake": 1, "Unmarked": -1})

# Feature selection
features = ["Rating", "User Review Count", "Feedback Useful", "Feedback Funny", "Feedback Cool", "Friend Count", "Text Length"]
X_train = df_train[features]
y_train = df_train["Review Class"]

X_test = df_test[features]
y_test = df_test["Review Class"]

# Data imputation (filling missing values with mean)
imputer = SimpleImputer(strategy="mean")
X_train_imputed = imputer.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test_imputed = imputer.transform(X_test)

# Train the logistic regression model
logreg = LogisticRegression()
logreg.fit(X_train_imputed, y_train)

# Make predictions on the testing set
y_pred = logreg.predict(X_test_imputed)

# Evaluate the model
accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
classification_report_str = classification_report(y_test, y_pred)
conf_matrix = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)

print(f"Accuracy: {accuracy}")
print("Classification Report:")
print(classification_report_str)
print("Confusion Matrix:")
print(conf_matrix)
```

and this is the result:

[image: Attempt 1]

This is the second code I attempted:

```
import pandas as pd
import nltk
import string
import re
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.stem.porter import PorterStemmer
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, precision_score, recall_score, f1_score

# Preprocessing functions
def text_lowercase(text):
    return text.lower()

def remove_numbers(text):
    result = re.sub(r'\d+', '', text)
    return result

def remove_punctuation(text):
    translator = str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)
    return text.translate(translator)

def remove_whitespace(text):
    return " ".join(text.split())

def remove_stopwords(text):
    stop_words = set(stopwords.words("english"))
    word_tokens = word_tokenize(text)
    filtered_text = [word for word in word_tokens if word not in stop_words]
    return " ".join(filtered_text)

stemmer = PorterStemmer()

def stem_words(text):
    word_tokens = word_tokenize(text)
    stems = [stemmer.stem(word) for word in word_tokens]
    return " ".join(stems)

lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()

def lemmatize_word(text):
    word_tokens = word_tokenize(text)
    lemmas = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(word, pos='v') for word in word_tokens]
    return " ".join(lemmas)

# Load the data
df_train = pd.read_csv("Yelp Training Set.csv")
df_test = pd.read_csv("Yelp Testing Set.csv")

# Preprocess the "Review Text" column
df_train["Review Text"] = df_train["Review Text"].apply(text_lowercase)
df_train["Review Text"] = df_train["Review Text"].apply(remove_numbers)
df_train["Review Text"] = df_train["Review Text"].apply(remove_punctuation)
df_train["Review Text"] = df_train["Review Text"].apply(remove_whitespace)
df_train["Review Text"] = df_train["Review Text"].apply(remove_stopwords)
df_train["Review Text"] = df_train["Review Text"].apply(stem_words)
df_train["Review Text"] = df_train["Review Text"].apply(lemmatize_word)

df_test["Review Text"] = df_test["Review Text"].apply(text_lowercase)
df_test["Review Text"] = df_test["Review Text"].apply(remove_numbers)
df_test["Review Text"] = df_test["Review Text"].apply(remove_punctuation)
df_test["Review Text"] = df_test["Review Text"].apply(remove_whitespace)
df_test["Review Text"] = df_test["Review Text"].apply(remove_stopwords)
df_test["Review Text"] = df_test["Review Text"].apply(stem_words)
df_test["Review Text"] = df_test["Review Text"].apply(lemmatize_word)

# Prepare your labeled and unlabeled data
X_labeled = df_train[["User Review Count", "Feedback Useful", "Feedback Funny", "Feedback Cool", "Friend Count", "Text Length"]]
y_labeled = df_train["Review Class"]

X_unlabeled = df_test[["User Review Count", "Feedback Useful", "Feedback Funny", "Feedback Cool", "Friend Count", "Text Length"]]

# Initialize your model
model = LogisticRegression()

# Train your model on the labeled data
model.fit(X_labeled, y_labeled)

# Use the model to predict labels for the unlabeled data
pseudo_labels = model.predict(X_unlabeled)

# Cluster the unlabeled data using KMeans
num_clusters = 2  # You can adjust this based on your data and needs
cluster_model = KMeans(n_clusters=num_clusters)
cluster_labels = cluster_model.fit_predict(X_unlabeled)

# Use the cluster labels to filter the pseudo-labels
good_clusters = [0]  # You can adjust this based on your data and needs
X_filtered = []
y_filtered = []
for i in range(len(X_unlabeled)):
    if cluster_labels[i] in good_clusters:
        X_filtered.append(X_unlabeled.iloc[i])
        y_filtered.append(pseudo_labels[i])

# Ensure that X_filtered and X_labeled have the same columns
# In this example, we assume both dataframes have the same columns,
# but you should adjust this code if they have different columns.
X_filtered = pd.DataFrame(X_filtered, columns=X_labeled.columns)

# Retrain the model on the filtered data (labeled + pseudo-labeled)
X_combined = pd.concat([X_labeled, X_filtered])
y_combined = pd.concat([y_labeled, pd.Series(y_filtered)])

model.fit(X_combined, y_combined)

# Make predictions on the test data using the retrained model
y_pred = model.predict(X_unlabeled)

# Calculate evaluation metrics
accuracy = accuracy_score(df_test["Review Class"], y_pred)
precision = precision_score(df_test["Review Class"], y_pred, average='weighted')
recall = recall_score(df_test["Review Class"], y_pred, average='weighted')
f1 = f1_score(df_test["Review Class"], y_pred, average='weighted')

print("Accuracy:", accuracy)
print("Precision:", precision)
print("Recall:", recall)
print("F1 Score:", f1)
```

and this is my result:

[image: Attempt 2]

Can someone please tell me where I'm going wrong?